# Communicating through pipes and sending messages

Tags: c

I am having trouble communicating with the child process. I am trying to make quick.c simply get an input from stdin and send it to sand.c to capitialise it and send it back to the parent and then print it to stdout. Right now the program asks for an input twice instead of only asking once.

this is quick.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int fds[2];
    int test[2];
    int pid;
    pid_t child_a;
    char buffer[50], buff[50];
    if(pipe(fds)) {
        perror("Pipe:");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(pipe(test)) {
        perror("Pipe:");
        exit(0);
    }
    child_a = fork();

    if (child_a == 0) {
        //Child 
        FILE *f = fdopen(fds[0], "r");
        FILE *e = fdopen(test[1], "w");
        close(fds[1]);
        close(test[0]);
        //dup2(fds[0],0); causes infinite loop
        dup2(test[1],1);
        
        execlp("./sand", "sand", NULL);
        fclose(e);
        fclose(f);
    } else {
        // Parent
            // Wrap the pipes
            FILE *f = fdopen(fds[1], "w");
            FILE *e = fdopen(test[0], "r");
            
            close(fds[0]);
            close(test[1]);
            
            fgets(buffer,50, stdin);
            fprintf(f,"%s",buffer);

            while(fgets(buff, 50, e)) {
                printf("Parent receive %s", buff);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
            fclose(f);
            fclose(e);

            wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This method is sand.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[50];
    int i = 0;
    fgets(buffer,50,stdin);
    char chr; 

    // Loop
    while (buffer[i]) { 
        buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]); 
        i++; 
    } 
    fprintf(stdout,"%s",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `dup2` you need another close.  The boiler plate is: `pipe(fd); ... close(fd[0]); dup2(fd[1], 1); close(fd[1])`   It's a little weird to `close` after `execl`.  If those `close` ever execute, it is because `execl` failed, so there should be an error message.

Comment: Note the primary issue here is the commented out line.  SInce you don't dup stdin for the child, the first line of input goes to the parent and is written into the pipe and never read.  The second line of input is read directly by the child (not from the pipe), converted to uppercase and written into the pipe to be read by the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On running the code in my machine, the commented dup2 line does not loop to infinity. That may be because pipe programs run differently on different machines. However, the program terminates after taking input. Here are the things that are wrong with your code:

1. You aren't waiting for the child to write data to test pipe before printing in the parent. You must put the wait statement after taking input.
2. You've used file pointers for handling pipes. Pipes are accessed with file descriptors and cause unexpected results when handled with file pointers. Instead of fgets and fprintf, use read and write methods to work with file descriptors.
3. Error in the execlp command which I've commented.
4. There are errors regarding buffers, I've commented them in the code where they occur.

This is quick.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int fds[2];
    int test[2];
    int pid;
    pid_t child_a;
    char buffer[50], buff[50];
    if(pipe(fds)) {
        perror("Pipe:");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(pipe(test)) {
        perror("Pipe:");
        exit(0);
    }
    child_a = fork();

    if (child_a == 0) {
        //Child 
        //CHANGED: No need to open file pointers here. Pipes are already open and accessed by file descriptor instead of file pointer. File pointers create trouble when used with pipes. 0 is file descriptor of stdin, 1 for stdout.
        
        close(fds[1]);
        close(test[0]);
        dup2(fds[0],0);
        dup2(test[1],1);
        
        //CHANGED: There was an error with the command you wrote.
        //That's because ./sand arg will look for a 'sand' directory which doesn't exist
        //This line will throw warnings because execlp requires needs a command as the second argument, but in this case the filename is the command.
        //NOTE: before running quick.c, compile sand.c as sand.out and not a.out
        execlp("./sand.out",NULL);
        printf("Exec Error\n");            //this will only execute if execlp didn't run. Always have this line in your code to know what's happening.
    } 
    else 
    {
            // Parent
            // Wrap the pipes
            //Got rid of the file pointers
            close(fds[0]);
            close(test[1]);
            
            //CHANGE: fgets is only used with file pointers. While handling pipes, we work with file descriptors, with which read and write methods are used
            int n = read(0,buffer,50);         //If this is new to you, I strongly recommend reading manual pages for read and write, but for right now
                                               // The signature should be enough to understand - read/write(int file_descriptor, char *buffer, int number_of_bytes)
            write(fds[1],buffer,n);
      
            //MOST IMPORTANT: You need to wait for child after this point. Because test pipe doesn't have data yet which will be received by child.
            wait(NULL);
            
            //CHANGE: printf statements do not work well with buffere, because buffers are not terminated with null
            //%s specifier will always look for a null or print garbage
            //If you still want to use printf, look into $man bzero
            
            while((n = read(test[0],buff, 50))>0) 
            {
                write(1,buff,n);
            }
            fflush(stdout);            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is sand.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char buffer[50];
    int i = 0;
    int n = read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));     //changed fgets to read, to get number of bytes read.
    char chr;

    // Loop
    // we have number of bytes. So change while to for
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]); 
    } 
    write(1,buffer,n);                //Changed fprintf to write to get rid of %s problem. 
                                      //Again, to fill remaining places of buffer with null, look up bzero. 
                                      //The reason I haven't done that is to not confuse you with so many changed methods. 
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know, if the solution also helps you find the source of the infinity loop.

Comment: The source of the infinite loop (not really an infinite loop, just blocking on IO) is the failure to close the fds after the dup2.  Just do `dup2(fds[0],0); close(fds[0])` (and similarly for the other pipe).

Comment: There's no need to `wait`.  You can synchronize on the IO by blocking on the read.

Comment: Wow! I didnt know I had to close after dup2, because I've never faced any errors with that. Can you elaborate further on synchronizing IO? I have never done that. I always use wait in inter process communication.

Comment: It is completely reasonable to use `wait`, but not strictly necessary here since the parent is going to block on the read until the child exits.  It is certainly best practice to use `wait` to avoid the child becoming a zombie, but in this case the parent will exit quickly so it's no more necessary than closing files and freeing memory before exiting.  Nice to do, but not really necessary.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense